# How to print the sending data of multipart entity in android

Tags: android, multipartentity

I have uploading the multiple image and some string data to php server.I want to print the data want i'm sending into the sever.I have tried something like this

class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask {

```
String sResponse = null;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Room_addroom1.this, "Uploading",
            "Please wait...", true);
    dialog.show();
}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        String url ="http://airbnb.abservetech.com/demo/public/mobile/hotel/roomsadd";
        int i = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
        System.out.println("i---"+i);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userid", null);

        Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(map.get(i));

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        entity = new MultipartEntity();

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();


        byte[] res=bos.toByteArray();


        entity.addPart("room_images", new ByteArrayBody(data,
                "image/jpeg", params[1]));


        entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("52"));
        entity.addPart("room_type",new StringBody( "premium"));
        entity.addPart("room_prize", new StringBody("2356"));


        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        entity.writeTo(bytes);
        Log.e("mainToPost", "roommainToPost----" + entity.toString());

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
                localContext);
        sResponse = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());


    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

    }
    return sResponse;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
    try {
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();

        if (sResponse != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    sResponse + " Photo uploaded successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            count++;
            if (count < map.size()) {
                new ImageUploadTask().execute(count + "", "hm" + count
                        + ".jpg");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

}

But the output display like this

```
E/mainToPost: roommainToPost----org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity@42f2d390
```

How to print the all sending values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 String entityContentAsString = new String(byteoutputstream.toByteArray());
    Log.e("multipartEntitty:", "" + entityContentAsString);
```

try this.